# How to implemented a KNN classifier with custom weighting for training observations

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, knn

I want to implement a KNN classifier where for each observation in my training set, I have a weighting variable (a measure of accuracy). In other words, I would like neighbours with a high weighting to contribute more significantly to the class probability estimation of a test observation. How can I incorporate this weighting in R? Is there an existing algorithm that can do this?

Comment: Figure all KNN classifiers would be custom to a given set of data, as against other data. You might take a look at packages KKNN and FNN and https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJorj9lqLNAhXB7BQKHY0HAfAQFghIMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikibooks.org%2Fwiki%2FData_Mining_Algorithms_In_R%2FClassification%2FkNN&usg=AFQjCNHcuD8Fdn4lvvTVhtCTXW2Z-_yWcA&sig2=sluqfHJc7XN5BUkVZ8pqbg for discussion. Is you research spatial, temporal, or a more arbitrary form of neighborliness?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the following 2 parts tutorial.
It's helpful I guess in our case.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtgJEVxl7DY&t=647s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkLNb0CXw84&t=603s

Knn does compare the weight of each attribute by default by comparing patterns of different rows by measuring the distance between the test point and the training set.

Hope that helps